# Using of to and for before verbs

Tags: verbs, infinitives

Let's see two sentences.

1. I am thanking God to make me separate from you.
2. I am thanking God for making me separate from you.

I know that the first one is incorrect. But why can't I use "to make" here? What is the rule here?

I apologise if the question is too basic.

Comment: The use of the preposition “for” with the verb “thank” is idiomatic in English. https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/verbs-and-prepositions

Comment: You thank someone _for something_. _Something_ must be a noun.

Comment: Also, "I *am thanking* God" sounds strange in American English, unless someone asked you "What are you doing *right now*?"  Otherwise, we would just say "I *thank* God", because it's a general truth, not a process going on right now.

Comment: @stangdon - I am thanking God I didn't buy any Bitcoins (I wasn't going to anyway).

Comment: I don't think that "thanking God" sounds odd in AmE or any English. It all depends on context. I can imagine a character in a movie or play saying this. Check out the Pastor's Corner here: https://d2y1pz2y630308.cloudfront.net/16981/bulletins/20201213.pdf

Comment: "Thanking God" is fine.  "Thanking God to make" is unclear and incorrect use.    Can you explain the situation?  What is the speaker thankful for, exactly?

Comment: @Lambie Use of the present continuous here "I am thanking God for...", as opposed to "I thank God for..." sounds idiomatically Indian to me.

Comment: @WS2 "Why are you on your knees, Lizzie?" Answer: I'm thanking God for [whatever].

Comment: @Lambie In that context - yes I agree. I was thinking of circumstances where a person was not at that moment in the act of prayer.

Comment: Note that it is not a matter of "_to_ or _for_ before verbs": it is a matter of "_to_ or _for_ after the (specific) word _thank_".

Answer (score 0):

[CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thank) defines *thank*.

> verb [ T ]A2
> to express to someone that you are pleased about or are grateful **for something** that **they have done** [emphasis added]:
> He thanked me **for taking** him home.

> thank sb for sth

> If you thank someone for something, you mean that they are responsible or to blame for it:
> You can thank John **for** the mess we're in.
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thank-sb-for-sth)

As @Michael Harvey has rightly said and as shown above, we have a **gerund/noun** after *for*.

In the above examples, the **something** has been done.

There is a usage with **to**, but it is different from the above examples.

> I'll thank you to do sth

> formal
> used to **ask someone**, in an annoyed way, **to do something** [emphasis added]:
> I'll thank you to leave my private papers alone.
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-ll-thank-you-to-do-sth)

In the **to** example,  the **something** has not been done.

Back to OP's questions, if the separation has happened, we could consider

> 2. I thank God for making me separate from you.

I agree with @stangdon that **thank God** is more common than **thanking God**.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thank+God%2Cthanking+God&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthank%20God%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthanking%20God%3B%2Cc0)

As you are clearly very annoyed with that somebody,  if the separation has not happened, we could consider

> 1. I will thank you to make me separate from you.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: I am thanking God **for** making...

verb     + object + preposition + -ing

(**thank**ing + God   + **for**         + making

[ We use a to-infinitive form to express purpose.

They started their journey early to avoid the traffic.

I went to the market to buy some food. We borrowed money to start a new business. He has gone to England to learn English.

We use for + (verb + ing) to talk about a reason for something.

She couldn't speak for laughing. He wears the old trousers for painting.

The general purpose of a thing-

This knife is used for cutting bread (function of the knife)

We can also say 'This knife is used to cut bread'. ]

Comment: This is not a purpose construction: they are not thanking God _in order to_ make them separate. It is a complement of _thank_, which happens to take the preposition "for".

Comment: @ Colin Fine
'     '- I completely agree with you. I said [    -    ... We thank somebody for (doing) something- I am thanking God for making... Thank you for  contributing to my answer.